# CMake - Make a list of paths absolute.

Tags: path, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a variable:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES
        ${PocoNetExternal_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Which comes from:

```
set(EXTERNAL_NAME PocoNetExternal)
    set(${EXTERNAL_NAME}_LIBRARIES
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXTERNAL_NAME}/Foundation/${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}PocoFoundation${POCO_build_postfix}${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXTERNAL_NAME}/Util/${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}PocoUtil${POCO_build_postfix}${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXTERNAL_NAME}/Net/${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}PocoNet${POCO_build_postfix}${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
       )
```

Because of the issue discussed in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040574/cmake-only-link-a-library-to-an-executable-if-it-is-needed?noredirect=1#comment79042394_46040574), I need all of these paths to be relative.

I have tried this:

```
function(makeLibPathsAbsolute)

    set(temp ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES})    #rename list
    set(external_libraries_rel)                        #make empty list

    list(LENGTH temp len1)                 #len1 is length of temp list
    math(EXPR len2 "${len1} - 1")           #len2 is len1 - 1

    foreach(val RANGE ${len2})                                 #for val = 0 to len2
        list(GET temp ${val} relPath)                         #relPath becomes the {val} entry of temp
        get_filename_component(absPath ${relPath} ABSOLUTE)   #make relPath Absolute and call it absPath
        list(APPEND external_libraries_rel ${absPath})        #Append this to the external_libraries_rel list
    endforeach()

endfunction()
```

But when I use `target_link_libraries(${name} ${external_libraries_rel})` I get an Undefined Reference Error for all of the functions related to the library I am trying to link. Indicating that the library has not actually been linked.

Is my `makeLibPathsAbsolute()` function correct?

Comment: You don't seem to return anything from your function. Can you check that variable passed to `target_link_libraries` isn't empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all variables set in the function are not visible outside. (In other words, variable's definition is **scoped** to the function).

For make variable visible for the function's caller, use *PARENT_SCOPE* option of the [set()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html) command.

E.g. you may "publish" `external_libraries_rel` list by appending this line to the end of the function:

```
set(external_libraries_rel ${external_libraries_rel} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Comment: @arrowd: Why have you deleted your own answer? Except from missed option (I thought it was unintended), it shows nice way for **declare** and implement functions which should return something.

Comment: The main point in my post was omitting `PARENT_SCOPE`, but it turned out that this is impossible. As for returning from function using return args - I don't think this deserves a separate answer. Just add it to your post, if you wish.